# Professional bike mechanics & maintenance training courses

Tags: repair, training

Recently I have been doing some small fixes in own bikes, I have enjoyed it a lot, then comes to my mind the idea that would be nice to help others as well, but in a more professional way.

What is the most professional training one could take to become a bicycle technician?

Comment: Where are you based? Anyhow there are a lot of tutorials in youtube, in many languages from english to italian to spanish to french, to do most of the fix and repair and assembly needed.

Comment: Hello @EarlGrey, thanks for your answer, the YouTube videos are very handy for the know-how. I am based in Vienna, Austria -> Europe. There should be some place to get certified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper qualifications do exist, *for example* [the New Zealand Certificate in Bicycle Mechanics](https://www.careers.govt.nz/qualifications/view/2897/8365).

But like many training courses in this world, the proof's in the doing more than the bookwork.

I'd suggest you start by looking around your area for a [bike cooperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_cooperative) and volunteer some time.

A couple of large well-known co-ops are:

- https://www.thehubbikecoop.org/
- https://thebristolbikeproject.org/

Don't go on name - for example [Edinburgh Bike Coop](https://www.edinburghbicycle.com/) seems to be purely a retail shop.

---

https://www.fahrrad.co.at/ seems to be local to you but looks more like a retail shop, despite the name containing "cooperative"   If nothing else you could telephone them for advise.

Comment: Thanks @Criggie, it is true for Austria we have the following professional training ~2300 EUR -> https://www.wifi.at/kursbuch/handwerk-weitere-gewerbe/weitere-gewerbe/fahrradtechnik/fahrrad-techniker-ausbildung

Answer (score 4):

Since you’ve stated in a comment that you live in Austria, I think the only specialised education for bicycle mechanics in Austria is an apprenticeship: https://www.berufslexikon.at/berufe/2898-FahrradmechanikerIn/ (Austrian job encyclopaedia)

In practice I think what matters most is experience (and of course taking your time, checking things, following proper procedures etc.). An education in mechanics, engineering or even physics helps a bit for basic understanding, but in the end there is no way around experience. You could get that by either owning and maintaining a lot of bicycles, working at a bicycle shop or volunteering at free bike repair events (here in Linz there is one in a week).

A bicycle is a very simple machine but there are tons of different components and compatibility is always a problem. Having all the right tools can also be difficult.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to learn on your own, the Park Tool Company [Repair Help website](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help) has a comprehensive collection of high quality, detailed articles and videos.

Along with reading and watching you need actual practical experience. If you want 'professional' training look for bicycle repair courses at local community colleges or adult education centers. Some bike shops also do some basic repair classes. Of course these may not be available during the COVID 19 pandemic.

Answer (score 2):

There is an accreditation from Cytech that is recognised in several countries around the world.

https://www.cytech.training/

Answer (score -1):

> What is the most professional training one could take to become a bicycle technician?

Why won't you ask the place where you plan to be employed? They most likely have some criteria for employment, and asking them directly instead of guessing incorrectly is a good plan. Bicycles are one of the simplest mechanical devices, and thus, they are repairable even without a formal education.

However, you should know that there is not a lot of money moving in the bicycle repair business. You said you live in Austria. I think it classifies as a high-income country. Most people living there probably buy mainly new bicycles, assembled in a low-income country, and throw them away when they break. Even wheels these days are very often machine-built. Thus, even being skilled in the art of wheelbuilding doesn't necessarily guarantee you a high and stable income.

Comment: They don't throw away bicycles after small problems. The more rich the people sre the more expensive bikes they buy. So the cost of a bike remains substantial. And because they make more money, they do not hesitate to use a dedicated service to repair their expensive bike or just to set it up for the season.

Comment: The answer is biased, the word "probably" says it all. There is no cause - effect to live in a rich country and people "throwing away" bicycles. With this pandemic the bike market grows (real statistics), government pushes people change habits of transport

Comment: Let me review my bikes, Kalkhoff, made in Germany, Husqvarna, Sweden, a city bike made in Belgium, one of my neighbors, yes from Bangladesh, quite dangerous to generalize

Comment: " one of the simplest mechanical devices"....A sledge hammer is a simple mechanical device. A bicycle - not so much, and if ever not for a long time.